# Making graph human friendly/readable (500 nodes, 1600 edges)

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I have decided to learn DOT language, which looks fantastic. I decided to make a project for making a graph for RPM building. I scan all the recipes to build RPM packages and also add information about required patches and imports. Currently my graph has under 500 nodes and more than 1600 edges, and the size should be stable +/- 50-100 nodes/edges from time to time.

Here is what I have now:

- (sfdp) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/deptree1.jpg/
- (dot) [fragment] http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/deptree2.jpg/
- (twopi) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/28/deptree3.jpg/

The first two are a bit more readable then the last one.

Details:

- Packages are in black bordered boxes.
- Patches are in orange bordered boxes + orange edges.
- Imports are in red bordered boxes + red edges.
- There are no single root package node. We could say there are several top level (root) package nodes, 4-10 nodes packages (nodes), which import most of the packages.
- There are standalone package (nodes), not dependencies and no on depends upon them.
- Patches can be only (mostly) used by single package node.
- Not all packages nodes has patches. I would say smaller part of packages nodes have them.
- Import files can be included in a huge part of package nodes (e.g., 1/3 of all package nodes).
- I have rankdir="TB" (Top-Bottom)
- I have increased the weight on the edges (package -> patch). Which should mean that patch nodes are closer to their package node.
- It would be nice to minimize number of edges overlaying nodes. This makes graph a lot unreadable.

Any suggestions on graph layout configuration and algorithm usage in this case?

Comment: In your code, how many iterations do you use? To me, the first version is the best, and is also the tool I've used for larger diagrams. I have always gotten stuck though because even though more iterations means more legibility, it also means that much more time to render.

Comment: can you refresh your pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Impressive graph!
I would try what happens if you

- give the edges a bit of transparency
- actually make them a bit longer. I know this makes the graph even larger, but it could make it visually a bit clearer, and if you're going to print it for example, the reduced font size you end up with might be set off by the structure coming across better.
- filling the nodes with a light version of their borders.
- make nodes very small and only give them index numbers. Then create a legend matching color + index number to the actual content. That might defy the purpose of your graph, but still, it might be worth trying. For starters, just leave out the labels and make tiny, colored circles. Shouldn't take too long and you might end up seeing some previously unseen structural properties. If you find anything useful, work your way back up to as little on-node information as possible until you find a good tradeoff.

Oh, and I've never managed to keep GraphViz from plotting edges over nodes either...